# An internal error occurred during: "Deploying JugaadFunda to Google". com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminFactory.setJarSplittingEnabled(Z)V

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloud, web-hosting

When I am trying to deploy my first application to Google App Engine, it gives me an error

> An internal error occurred during: "Deploying JugaadFunda to Google".
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminFactory.setJarSplittingEnabled(Z)V

I am really not getting where I am wrong. I would appreciate if someone helps.

Comment: Did you found an answer? Please say yes!

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when updating my App Engine SDK version from **1.9.54** to **1.9.61** (Using JRE7).

Getting back to **1.9.54** was my solution.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Same here. The error re: jar splitting occurred after updating from 1.9.59 to 1.9.63, so I switched back to 1.9.59 and I was able to deploy again. Remaining on an older version of the SDK is a workaround for now but one shouldn't stay behind for too long.

Comment: Does anyone have a link to an official download for 1.9.59? I can't seem to find one anywhere..

Edit: Found it! https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/appengine-sdks/featured/

Answer (score 3):

Update 27-Mar-2018
I did some more digging today and found the following:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72450185
So it appears everybody's getting pushed on to the Google Cloud SDK. This link also includes instructions on migrating over; I haven't tried this myself yet, so good luck.

Partial answer:
In SDK versions 1.9.60 or 1.9.61, the method

```
void setJarSplittingEnabled(boolean doSplit);
```

was removed from com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminFactory. 
When deploying a project, somewhere along the way, this method is being called and obviously doesn't resolve, the deployment aborts.
I can only speculate - looks like jar splitting isn't a thing any longer so it was removed from the SDK. As this is happening on a very old project of mine,  I suspect somewhere buried in the project settings is an old switch that triggers the call to that method. Easiest (not necessarily best) way would be for Google to re-introduce this method as a stub that does nothing so we can continue deploying our projects using current SDK versions. Or of course if somebody can point to a setting somewhere (that I couldn't locate), that would be even better.

Comment: If deploying through eclipse is not a compulsion, can be achieved via 'appcfg'. Documentation can be found here - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/uploadinganapp. I did for App Engine SDK version 1.9.59 and 1.9.64, and both worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as of today it is not possible anymore to deploy with App Engine SDK version 1.9.54. You are forced to upgrade to version 1.9.64, which leads to the 
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminFactory.setJarSplittingEnabled(Z)V problem. 
So I guess you are forced to upgrade to the cloud based SDK as of now (which I didn't manage to realise up to now). See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110066569.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation [1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/admin/AppAdminFactory) is is explained that the method

```
AdminFactory.setJarSplittingEnabled()
```

is used to divide the JAR files to ease their manipulation and upload. Deactivation of the function, however, can lead to failures if the files are too big.

Depending on what your value “Z” is, it might be the root of the problem. I do wonder also, what is that “V” doing after the sentence?, if this is not a typo of the answer, I recommend you to delete it as it is part of an incorrect sentence syntax.

[Documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/admin/AppAdminFactory)

Answer (score 0):

Update your Eclipse Plugin - to Google Cloud SDK: https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/migrating-gpe