# Error deploying app engine project using Old Eclipse google plugin

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

Suddenly i got an error couple more days ago when going to deploy appengine project to some Project IDs .. Ex there are two project ids i have 
1) xxxx-dev.appspot.com and 2) xxxx-live.appspot.com

I can put my project xxxx-live.appspot.com with no issues but when i'm going to deploy my project to xxxx-dev.appspot.com environment i'm getting this error

```
Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/deploy?app_id=cloudschool-dev&version=spring-charith&
401 Unauthorized
Your version of the App Engine SDK is out-of-date. Please update your SDK at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download#appengine_sdk and your Maven plugin, if necessary, according to the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven


See the deployment console for more details
Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/deploy?app_id=cloudschool-dev&version=spring-charith&
401 Unauthorized
Your version of the App Engine SDK is out-of-date. Please update your SDK at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download#appengine_sdk and your Maven plugin, if necessary, according to the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven
```

Can some one help me to fix this error 
Also i have a small team .. but some of my team members can deploy it to "xxxx-dev.appspot.com" environment with no issues .. :(

Comment: Review|Help and Improvement: corrected formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have deployed my appengine application many times, suddenly something went wrong

I too faced the exact same issue, I tried deploying the same project with other machine with same login credential it worked fine, Which clarifies me that there is no any issue with the Code or Google Cloud Platform Environment

So I tried to update the Google App Engine Plugin which fixed the issue, Before installing new Eclipse you can give a try with this, to fix your problem

GoTo Help-> Insatall New Softwares

and Type the url "http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.5"

[image: In Mycase I used 4.5 because I'm using Mars]

The Above image taken after updating the plugin, While I'm Getting the Issue "All items are installed" was not shown there

We wont be facing such an issue in future because Google is moving towards Cloud Tools and Google plugin for Eclipse has been stopped from the version "Eclipse Oxygen"

Answer (score 1):

Hello @charith Migunthenna,

One of my colleague has faced the same issue. He has downloaded the latest version of eclipse, which fixed this issue.
[Download from here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

Comment: Updating Eclipse seems like a good idea, remember also to download "Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin" last version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The ~/.appcfg_oauth2_token_java (it's for java users, for python users it's ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens) had the wrong Google cloud credentials. I deleted the file and tried deploying again. The deployment took me through the Google OAuth flow and then it worked. The file automatically gets created after the successful OAuth.

The location of the file in your PC is... C:\Users\niks (your user account name)

Comment: Cool ... This did it for me! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

In older Eclipse versions upgrading the Google App Engine plugin is not possible. In that case installing a newer Eclipse version is necessary.

However, for some of us that switch is not that simple. Newer Eclipse versions don't support Java 7 (yes, we should all update to Java 8) and some libraries that our legacy code is using are not supported in Java 8.

For servers that are decently loaded and should have no hiccups or bigger downtime, the more careful approach would be to do the upgrade in few steps - first replacing the legacy code/libraries and then switching to Java 8 and a new development environment. Which is a bit harder to do now with the error that is showing up.

So this is the answer for those who are in similar situation like me. Hopefully it will help someone.

The oldest Google App Engine SDK that is supported now is 1.9.60. So you need to download that one (you can find it [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.60)) and unpack it on your computer. Next, you need to change your project's Google App Engine settings and make it use that specific SDK.

If you try to deploy your code to Google App Engine now, it will fail with a completely new [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48294615/an-internal-error-occurred-during-deploying-jugaadfunda-to-google-com-google). That SO thread contains a workaround as well, in a comment though - deploy is still possible but not through Eclipse. You should use `appcfg` command line tool. Documentation for `appcfg` is [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/uploadinganapp).

That should be it. Once you are sure everything works fine, switching to Java 8 and the latest Eclipse should be less stressful.